# Is this a foundation problem - void space underneath exterior brick wall

Tags: foundation, slab

We moved into this house 5 years ago and did not find a piece of dead tree root at the bottom of the wall until yesterday. It seems the previous owner cut the tree, but here is a small damage to the brick.

When we dug further, we found underneath the wall there is an empty space. I could feel some hard material, possibly concrete slab a few inches inside the hole. And when I dug further the space just extends along the wall to the left. There is concrete slab on my right side although it is not clear on the picture.

Is this a foundation problem? Can I buy some concrete and fill it up or do I need to call a contractor?

Thanks.

Photo one:
[image: void]

Photo two, a closer look:
[image]

Comment: Bricks and mortar are not cracking/moving down, so dig/clean the empty space and fill in with concrete.  It seems to be small, a foot or two, maybe a few inches deep, clean to good concrete and fill in.  If digging/cleaning finds it being a large area or cracks, re-assessment needed.

Comment: @crip659 thank you for the advice. I'll dig further to have a better idea of the problem 
tomorrow.